# MVC3 HTML Helper for large Text area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have an html helper:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
```

But it is too small for the data in that property of my Model.  Descriptino is a 1000 character string.  I need the user to be able to enter several lines of text and have it wrap in the HTML object.  How do I do this?

Comment: This is so simple! You can learn many things from VisualStudio's intellisense. However @Javad_Amiry supplies a great answer for a simple question. Cool and perfect

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try

```
Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new {@cols="80" , @rows="4" })
```

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description)

// or a full option-list is:
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, 
    rows, // the rows attribute of textarea for example: 4
    columns, // the cols attribute of textarea for example: 40
    new { }) // htmlAttributes to add to textarea for example: @class = "my-css-class"
```

**Notice:** you can use `null` instead of `new { }` for `htmlAttributes` but it is not recommended! It's strongly recommended that use a blank `new { }` -that represents a `new object`-

Comment: A great answer for a simple question. Cool and perfect

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EditorFor`, but in that case it's better to define your own EditorTemplate for rendering your TextArea, using `TextAreaFor` or whatever it's needed.

The main difference between the `TextAreaFor` and `EditorFor` is that, if I've understood well how everything works, when using EditorFor, Templates are taken into account, while when using `TextAreaFor` you choose the HTML Input used for rendering.

Templates seems interesting, I'm just starting digging into writing my own.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're after [Html.TextAreaFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.textareaextensions.textareafor.aspx).